# Make code blocks vertically resizable

Tags: feature-request, code

Currently, you can resize the "add answer" text-area box vertically using the grippie [sic] at the bottom.  I would love to be able to do this with the code-boxes that are found in both the question and answers that have vertical scroll bars.

This keeps the blocks vertically short for people skimming the page, but enables someone who wants to take a closer look at the code more space.  I know copy/paste to external editor is an option, but sometimes I may not have a editor open with syntax highlighting, not to mention keeping everything local to the SO page would be nice.

Comment: I'd love love _horizontal resizing_. I detest horizontal scrollbars.

Comment: @sarnold while I also dislike horizontal scroll, a vertical resize would still fit with the current style/flow of SO, while a horizontal would not (unless it floated above all other content, I suppose)

Comment: @sarnold I'd love auto inserting linebreaks in long lines to prevent horizontal scrollbars altogether and to encourage writing readable code.