# Panning in code blocks

Tags: feature-request, usability, code-block

Would it be a good (and feasible) idea to have panning in code blocks?

People keep pasting these wide-spaces unreadable code blocks. I'm sometimes willing to do someone else's styling job, but not before I know the question is worth editing at all. The combination of scrolling up/down and left/right is tiring. Panning would be very helpful to get a quick impression of what a code-block is about.

[image]

There have been all kinds of requests to facilitate reading code blocks, most of them proposing some resizing feature

- [Make code blocks vertically resizable](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93464/168269)
- [Resizable text blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92179/168269)
- [Way to expand code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/152874/168269)
- [Wider code-blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132362/168269)
- [Shortcut or button for copying posted code from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/32625/168269)

(to name a few)

Maybe there are a good reasons why such features have never been implemented. Panning/dragging (as in http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) might be a happy medium.

The Android has a [similar feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/192416/168269). (but of course Android and html are totally different).

Comment: Mouse-based panning would eliminate the easiest way to select and copy text.

Comment: This is why, when possible, I edit code blocks to eliminate horizontal scrolling.

Comment: While I like this idea, @Charles has a good point; that's why many (decent) programmers (even those who don't use vim) don't have lines that require horizontal scrolling. Just use multiple lines; it's not like you're coding an assembly pneumonic that's over 80 characters?

Comment: @Charles You are right and I had this in mind when I included the last meta link. I admit it's a problem, maybe a dilemma. As for eliminating scrolling - of course we shouldn't have wide-spaced code blocks. I just wish each OP would think that way.

Comment: @ColeJohnson pneumonic - lung disease?

Comment: @GertArnold you are free to edit the code block to remove the need for horizontal scrolling as long as you don't edit the _code itself_

Comment: @Rosinante mnemonic* (speech to text)

Comment: Feels like a browser or mouse feature to me. (Using my touchpad, I can already pan everywhere by using two fingers to scroll, which can move in any direction. And implementing it in JavaScript would start another discussion: should moving down the pointer [move the content up or down](http://superuser.com/questions/319258/why-does-mac-lion-reverse-the-direction-of-my-mouse-scroll)?)